# M2 Search Result Not Displaying Correct Result/Products

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, search, catalogsearch

I've a multi-store setup using multi-website approach.

For some products, when I run a search query, I am not getting correct results, instead completely unrelated products are getting displayed.

The site is using the default MySQL Search.

Comment: Can you provide an example? Usually it's pulling up results because of words in the description or other attributes that are set to indexed for search so it's hard to tell why these results are coming up

Comment: For keywords like like iPhone screen or say bag, it is showing correct results. But for this one particular query, like "sim card holder" it's not showing the correct result at all.

When I configured 3rd party search extensions such as Algolia or Instant search, it's running fine. But the default Magento Search doesn't seem to be giving correct results for some query/keywords.